What's the name of this constant similar to that of Hermite's?
Recently i've been thinking about base reduction of lattices, and this constant similar to Hermites constant came up. Let $L$ be a lattice with basis $\mathbf{b}_{1},\ldots,\mathbf{b}_{n}$. We define the orthogonality defect of the basis as
$$
\delta(\mathbf{b}_{1},\ldots,\mathbf{b}_{n}) := \dfrac{\|\mathbf{b}_{1}\|\cdot\ldots\cdot\|\mathbf{b}_{n}\|}{\|\mathbf{b}_{1}^{*}\|\cdot\ldots\cdot\|\mathbf{b}_{n}^{*}\|}.
$$
where $\mathbf{b}_{1}^{*},\ldots,\mathbf{b}_{n}^{*}$ denotes the Gram-Schmidt ortogonalization of the basis. Then we can define the orthogonality defect of a lattice $L$ as
$$
\delta(L):=\min_{\substack{\mathbf{b}_{1},\ldots,\mathbf{b}_{n}\\ \text{ basis of $L$}}}{\delta(\mathbf{b}_{1},\ldots,\mathbf{b}_{n})}.
$$
What i'm interested in is the constant
$$
\delta_{n}:= \sup\limits_{L\in\mathcal{L}_{n}}\delta(L)
$$
where $\mathcal{L}_{n}$ denotes the set of all $n$ dimensional lattices. Is there a name for this? Anyone know anything about this?

It is known that
$$
(\sqrt{n}/12)^n\leq \delta_n \leq n^n.
$$
See Theorem 1.41 and Lemma 1.42 of Rothvoss' notes.

Thanks! I only knew the upper bound. I'm mainly interested in calculating the exact values in low dimensions. I wonder if anyone have done that already...

The exact bound for HKZ-reduced basis (so not exactly what you want, but likely “close”) has been computed in small dimensions, see here.
